# How to add heterogenous item dynamically to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView, in which it's backed by an ArrayList as datasource. I was required to insert some native ads between N items.

Now the problem is, I cannot map my current adapter position back to item correctly when a native ad view is added.

My solution for now is creating a view, which combining my item's view and the native ads view. Whenever the adapter position is equal to

```
position % N == 0
```

I will show the ad view together with the item. Though works, but it's not matching the requirement and seems not a very good way to do so.